# selecting multiple checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

I wrote a jquery code to send values to a php file

```
$('#def_formSubmit').live("click",function(){

        var query_string = '';
                    
                    $("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='assotop']").each(
                        function()
                        {
                            if(this.checked)
                            {
                                query_string += "&assotop[]=" + this.value;
                            }
                        });

    
    var def_tags = $("#tags").val();
    
    var dataString = 'def_tags='+ def_tags + query_string  ;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#QRresult").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' />");
        },
        success: function(data5) {
            $("#QRresult").html(data5);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But it does not work and does not sendi checkbox values to my php file.

I think this way of getting checkbox values is a old approach and not working for jquery 1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@` from your selector. This changed as of `1.3`

```
$("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='assotop']").each(
```

should be:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='assotop']").each(
```

<s>You could also do:</s>

```
$("input:checkbox[name='assotop']").each(
```

**EDIT:** Added `input` to the selector as noted by @lonesomeday.

**EDIT:** I guess I'd use the one with `input[type='checkbox']` so that `querySelectorAll` will be used in browsers that support it.

Comment: perhaps use `input:checkbox` too?

Comment: +1, but `input:checkbox` will be much quicker, since it doesn't have to select every element and then check it for being an `input` element.

Comment: @lonesomeday - I thought `:checkbox` took care of that. Perhaps I'm mistaken. I'll update. EDIT: Looking at the docs, I see you're correct. Thanks. :o)

Comment: @lonesomeday: Why not just use `:checkbox` which is much faster, you don't need `input` there with it.

Comment: @Sarfraz - [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/): *`$(':checkbox')` is equivalent to `$('*:checkbox')`, so `$('input:checkbox')` should be used instead.*

Comment: @patrick: O should have headed over there, thanks for that :)

Comment: @Sarfraz - I made the same mistake at first. :o)

Comment: @lonesomeday - It appears as though `:checkbox` is not supported by `querySelectorAll` while `[type=checkbox]` is. As such, I guess I'd use `[type=checkbox]` so that browsers that support `querySelectorAll` (including IE8) will get the performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectAll").change(function(){
        $(".sports").prop('checked', ($(this).is(':checked')));
    });
    $(".sports").change(function(){
        $("#selectAll").prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```